# Black Image Appear when Saving?

Tags: android, image

In these days, Images make me nervous. Now, the saving image turn into black color. I saved a photo with colourful but when saving, it gets only the whole black color. I don't know what is my problem. Give me some help.

Here is my code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
     Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
     ByteArrayOutputStream bao= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, bao);
     byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
     imageSave = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

It's appear like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Here is my answers.

```
  public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
     Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
     imageSave = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(myBitmap), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "myImage.jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```